# fprintf outputs 0x08 when printing backspace

Tags: c, linux, printf, ascii, vt100

When trying to print a backspace `("\b \b")` to a file (in `C`), it would show up as an unicode character (0x08).

Does this have to do with the format of the file I am printing to or the emulation of the terminal?

[image: Hello through backspace.]

Also, on an unrelated question I am trying to find out how to read arrow key inputs from `getch()`.

Comment: I think you can't read the arrow keys with `getch()`, it's also a non standard function so avoid it.

Comment: I added it in my code. Took it right from ncurses.

Comment: What's the problem? backspace is 0x08...

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to ask. There's no code. There is an unrelated question. There are just so many things, SO wrong with this question. However as I see you're new here, I'm not gonna -1 this:

1) Try to make your question clear: You want the backspaces to show? You want them to delete text? "I expected this but got that result" is a good start.

2)Add the code you're using. We can't say much without that.

3) Unrelated questions should be a different question so delete that

Comment: I'll try again: What does "When trying to print a backspace" mean?
What do you expect to appear?

Comment: There's no guarantee that the backspace will be destructive. It normally moves the current writing position back one place, so `hello\b\b` places the current writing position over the second `l`. If you then add a character such as `X`, you will see `helXo` and the current writing position will be over the `o`; another `X` makes what's visible into `helXX`.  All that assumes a simple terminal emulation. If your terminal emulator outputs the 'quad' with digits 0, 0, 0, 8, then maybe you have UTF-16 characters instead, and then the rules could be different. Are you on Windows? What codeset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to delete characters from an existing file, you should use fseek. printing '\b' won't help.

Comment: Got it. `fseek(pfile , -1 , SEEK_CUR);
   putc('\0', pfile);`

Comment: @CIAAbigguy Only if you want a 0x00 in the file.

Comment: Hmm, how do I properly delete characters?